# MUL operation result

Tags: assembly, x86

Please explain how MUL operation works in this situation:

**MUL ECX**

Before operation:

EAX: 000062F7 (25335)
ECX: 3B9ACA00 (1000000000)
EDX: 00000000 (0)

After operation:

EAX: C3ACE600
EDX: 0000170A (5898)

Would be thankful if anyone can explain me how 5898 was calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplication of two 32-bit values can yield a 64-bit result.

The result of `MUL` is stored in EDX:EAX.  (The upper 32 bits in EDX, the lower 32 bits in EAX).

```
0x3b9aca00 * 0x62f7 = 0x170a c3ace600
   ECX        EAX       EDX    EAX
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple actually. The description of `MUL r/m32` (`r/m32` refers to `ECX` in this case) is:

```
MUL r/m32  (EDX:EAX ← EAX ∗ r/m32).
```

So `EAX` is multiplied by `ECX` to form a 64-bit product which is stored in `EDX:EAX` (i.e. the low 32 bits end up in `EAX`, and the high 32 bits in `EDX`).

So if we punch in `000062F7 * 3B9ACA00` in a calculator, we get `170AC3ACE600`, meaning that `EAX` will be `C3ACE600` and `EDX` will be `170A` (or 5898 in base10).